# Using a jquery form with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsx

I'm new on using ReactJS. I have a form that's writing on JQuery and I want to make it on a React Component. How can I do that, Please?

```
(function($) {

"use strict";

var form = {
    field_input: $('.field-input'),
    init: function() {
        this.transformInput();
    },
    transformInput: function() {
        this.field_input.focus(function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('is-focused has-label');
        });

        this.field_input.blur(function(){
            var $parent = $(this).parent();
            if($(this).val() === ''){
                $parent.removeClass('has-label');
            }
            $parent.removeClass('is-focused');
        });

        this.field_input.each(function(){
            if($(this).val() !== ''){
                $(this).parent().addClass('has-label');
            }
        });
    }
};

window.form = form;
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write in `componentDidMount` and check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/use-react-with-other-libraries.html)